# C++ AMP with fast GPUs slower than CPU

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-amp

I'm just starting to learn C++ AMP and I've obtained a few examples that I've built with the VS 2012 RC, but I'm finding that the performance of the GPU is slower than the CPU.  For instance, the examples by Kate Gregory: http://ampbook.codeplex.com/releases/view/90595 (relevant to her upcoming book http://www.gregcons.com/cppamp/).  They were demonstrated by her in a lecture I watched where she obtained a ~5x performance improvement for the chapter 4 example by using her laptop's GPU (I believe she said it was a 6650) compared to CPU (not sure what CPU she had).  I've tried testing the example myself and on a  couple of system configurations (as below) I've always found the CPU to be faster.  I've also tested other examples and found the same.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a reason for the slower than expected performance?  Does anyone have an example that would definitely show the GPU being faster?

- System 1: Intel i7 2600K with onboard graphics (I expect this to be
  slower)
- System 2: Intel i7 2630QM with Intel HD switchable with AMD
  6770 (I have it running in performance mode so it should be using the
  6770)
- System 3: Intel i5 750 with 2xCrossfire AMD HD 5850

Example of results: chapter4 project results in 1.15ms CPU, 2.57ms GPU, 2.55ms GPU tiled.

**Edit**:

Doh, I think I just found the reason why - the values for the size of the matrices she used in the lecture were different.  The sample on the website uses M=N=W=64.  If I use 64, 512 and 256 as she did in the lecture then I get the corresponding ~5x increase in performance.

Comment: I wonder if [Kate Gregory](http://stackoverflow.com/users/203458/kate-gregory) is reading this.

Comment: If you do read it Kate then I think it would be good to update the online code to use the matrix sizes used in the lecture (http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2012/DEV334) - I was thinking there was something wrong with my VS or project settings as to why I wasn't seeing any improvement :)

Comment: Why are people voting to close this as "off topic"? What about C++ AMP, CPUs, GPUs, and Visual Studio is "off topic" for Stack Overflow?

Comment: The laptop I used at Tech Ed is a 4-core i7 with and AMD Radeon™ HD 6650M graphics card with 1GB VRAM, just for everyone's future reference

Comment: @FredLarson a google alert is a great way to hear every sparrow fall :-)

Comment: I recently tried the C++ AMP FFT implementation and it was much slower than IPP's CPU implementation (and it's not just copying time that can explain the difference).

Comment: BertR, if you post a repro of your scenario in our MSDN forum (or here on SO) we can help identify why you are not seeing the perf you were expecting. CarbonTwelve, we have many more samples for you to learn from. Links to the samples, forums, and a lot more from our blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/

Answer (score 7):

It seems like your overarching question is WHY moving things to the GPU doesn't always get you a benefit. The answer is copy time. Imagine a calculation that takes a time proprotional to n squared. Copying takes a time proportional to n. You might need quite a large n before spending the time to copy to and from the GPU is outweighed by the time saved doing the calculation there.

The book mentions this briefly in the early chapters, and Chapters 7 and 8 are all about performance and optimization. Chapter 7 is on Rough Cuts now; Chapter 8 should be there shortly. (Its code is already on Codeplex - the Reduction case study.)

I've just checked in an update to the Chapter 4 code that uses the Tech Ed starting numbers instead of the ones that were there before. Smaller matrices lose too much time to the copy to/from the GPU; larger ones take too long to be a good demo. But do feel free to play around with the sizes. Make them even larger since you don't mind a minute or two of "dead air", and see what happens.

Comment: I am aware of the cost of copy time, my question was basically just why the code I was using wasn't replicating the results with roughly the same platform.  Turns out the code wasn't identical, which is why.  Thanks for updating the code.